# CSS: Target body on Input:focus

Tags: html, css

Ive been looking around but have had no luck is it possible (with css) to target the body tag on      `input:focus` so for example when someone clicks on the input box i want the body to have `background:red`, im not sure if this is actually possible.

Thanks in advance.

Connor

Comment: Not possible without the use of javascript

Comment: [CSS Selector Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) supports this, but no browser has implemented it (it hasn't even been finalized yet).

Comment: What you're looking for is some kind of a parent selector.  This question's answer should answer yours too:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/262056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS. But it can be easily achieved with javascript / jQuery :)

This is how to do it in jQuery,

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    $("body").css({"background-color" : "red"});
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the color on blur!

Comment: Shame, Thanks though i will use this :)

Comment: @JosephSilber oh yeah! :)

Comment: @ConnorMiles if you found this useful, accept it as the answer so that people trying to answer will know that its solved! :)

Comment: Yes, ok chill i had to wait ten mins before i could accept thats why i give you a +1 in the meantime, could you please explain how i would toggle this so that on unfocus remove css?

Comment: @ConnorMiles you can use,
`$("input[type=text]").blur(function() { $("body").css({"background-color" : "none"});});` to remove the color on `unfocus` or `blur`

Comment: you can look up the documentation real quick in this site... http://dochub.io/

Answer (score 4):

This will be possible in the future with the [CSS4 parent selector](http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview), but for now you would have to use JavaScript.